# a* algorithm problem with one single edge

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, runtime-error

i'm having trouble with my python implementation of a* algorithm, but only with one edge.
When I run the code searching for path with the two broken nodes the code tries to compare single nodes to insert it in my priority queue, but i have defined another class, here's the code to help me explain to you

```
 def a_search(self, start, goal):
    if start not in self.connections or goal not in self.connections:
        raise Exception("Non sono stati forniti nodi validi.")
    frontier = PriorityQueue()
    frontier.put(PrioritizedItem(0, start))
    visited_path = {}
    estimated_cost = dict()
    visited_path[start] = None
    estimated_cost[start] = 0
    while not frontier.empty():
        current = frontier.get()
        current = current.get_node()
        if current == goal:
            break
        next_node: Node
        for next_node in self.connection(current):
            new_cost = estimated_cost[current] + self.pathweight(current, next_node)
            if next_node not in estimated_cost or new_cost < estimated_cost[next_node]:
                estimated_cost[next_node] = new_cost
                priority = new_cost + self.euristic(next_node, goal)
                frontier.put(PrioritizedItem(priority, next_node))
                visited_path[next_node] = current
    return frontier
```

Here's the class PrioritizedItem

```
@dataclass(order=True)
class PrioritizedItem:
priority: float
item: object = field()

def get_node(self):
    return self.item

def __cmp__(self, other):
    if self.priority < other.priority:
        return -1
    elif self.priority > other.priority:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: `__cmp__` doesn't do anything in Python 3 - that got replaced with rich comparison ages ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__cmp__` doesn't do anything in Python 3. It got replaced with [rich comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) ages ago - separate methods for each comparison operator, which can return arbitrary objects.

You're telling `dataclass` to generate comparison methods for you with `order=True`. If you don't want a field to be considered in comparisons, you can specify `compare=False` for that field... but then PrioritizedItem instances with the same priority and different items will be considered *equal*, which can have weird side effects.

Instead of changing comparison logic, the usual trick for handling this kind of thing is to just add an incrementing counter field to your elements and use that for tiebreaking, like `(priority, counter_value, item)` instead of `(priority, item)`. If you want to stick with a dataclass, you can add a field called `counter` or something between `priority` and `item`.

---

As an aside, if that `PriorityQueue` is the class from the `queue` module, you should use `heapq` instead. `queue.PriorityQueue` is specifically designed for use as a prioritized inter-thread message-passing system, and it has design decisions and overhead that don't make sense for single-threaded usage. For example, it blocks on `get` instead of raising an exception when there's nothing to get.